# Arduino hit counter

Tags: python, arduino, hitcounter

we are having a problem on getting data from the serial port. 
We have this python code, its purpose is to get a value from a file then increments it. We are trying to connect this to the arduino with a motor servo such that when it detects an increment, the servo moves.

```
#
# fetch counter 
#

import time
import urllib
import serial

# usb serial connection to arduino
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

last_counter = open("hitcounter.txt")
for b in last_counter:
b = b.strip()
while (True):
counter = open("hitcounter.txt")
for a in counter:
    a = a.strip()

delta = int(a) - int(b)
ass = delta+1
print ass
print "counter: %s, delta: %s" % (a, delta)
x=chr(ser.write(chr(ord(chr(delta)))))
print type(x)
print "%s" %(x)
y=ser.write(ass)

print type(y)
print "%s" %(y)
b = a
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: line indentation is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
while (True):
```

The line after it is not indented, so not part of the code block. Your code will simply idle loop here. :(

Assuming I understand your code logic:

```
#
# fetch counter 
#

import time
import urllib
import serial

# usb serial connection to arduino
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

last_counter = open("hitcounter.txt")

for b in last_counter:
    b = b.strip()

while (True):
    counter = open("hitcounter.txt")
    for a in counter:
        a = a.strip()

    delta = int(a) - int(b)
    ass = delta+1
    print ass
    print "counter: %s, delta: %s" % (a, delta)
    x=chr(ser.write(chr(ord(chr(delta)))))
    print type(x)
    print "%s" %(x)
    y=ser.write(ass)

    print type(y)
    print "%s" %(y)
    b = a
    time.sleep(10)
```